# Where is the specification for the Base Class Library?

Tags: .net, clr, standards, specifications, base-class-library

I am looking for the "definitive" specification for the Base Class Library.  I've perused ECMA 334, ECMA-335, IEC 23270, IEC 23271.  And I expected to find details for everything in all the standardized BCL namespaces (e.g., `System`, `System.Collections`, etc.) but it doesn't appear to be in those documents.

Is the specification just the .NET MSDN documentation or is there something else?

Am I missing the boat on how a CLI language and the .NET Framework fit together?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [zip](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-335.zip) at http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-335.htm contains documentation for the BCL classes.

Comment: I missed digging into the XML files, assuming that the PDFs were built from the XML... but the details are actually in there!  Thank you.